# Separation of Variables - Characteristic Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations

I have been solving PDEs using separation of variables for years now so I do it mechanically, without knowing **what I'm actually doing**! Help me understand.

$$tu_t = u_{xx}, \hspace{2.5cm} 0<x<\pi, t>1\\u(x,1) = sin(x) + 2sin(3x), \hspace{.5cm} 0\leq x\leq \pi\\u(0,t)=u(\pi,t) = 0,\hspace{2.9cm} t\geq 1$$

For the sake of the annotations:
$u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ 
$X''(x) +\lambda X(x) = 0$
$tT'(t) + \lambda T(t) = 0$

Now I only take two cases for X(X) when $\lambda > 0$ or $\lambda = \omega^2$:

$X''(x) + \omega^2 X(x) = 0 $ 
$X(x) = Acos(\omega x) + Bsin(\omega x) \hspace{2cm}$ which is the charac. equation.

when $\lambda < 0$ or $\lambda = -\omega^2$:
$X''(x) - \omega^2 X(x) = 0$ 
$X(x) = Ae^{\omega x} + Be^{-\omega x}\hspace{2cm}$ which is the charac. equation.

But what have I actually done here to find the characteristic equations?! I know theoretically by looking at it that I have integrated it twice but how?? What is this process even called (so I can search in literature)?

I ask this because of the $tu_t$ in the PDE, because I have to solve:
$T'(t) + \frac{\omega^2}{t}T(t) = 0$ and I have no clue of how to do that?

Thanks!

(Clarification: I know how to solve these PDEs, my question is only about the characteristic equations).

Comment: Separation of variables allows you to obtain a orthogonal set of eigenfunctions $\{X_n(x)\}$ that span the space of continuous functions on $[0,\pi]$, namely $\mathcal{C}[0,\pi]$. You can find these eigenfunctions by imposing your boundary conditions $X(0)=0=X(\pi)$, and you should get $X_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ for $n\geq 1$. Now assume $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(t)\sin (nx)$$ and find each $f_n(t)$.

Comment: @MatthewH. thanks for the explanation! I know how to proceed with the calculations, my question was about how I get the characteristic equations. I have made a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separation of variables reduces a single partial differential equation (PDE), which is an equation with multiple distinct partial derivatives, into several ordinary differential equations (ODEs) which are equations which only have a derivative with respect to a single variable.

The hope is that the ODEs are easier to solve, and once they have been solved the solution to the original PDE can be reconstructed from the solutions.

The equation for the $x$ variable is $X''+ \lambda X=0$ which is a *second order constant coefficient equation*. Such equations can be solved by the ansatz $X(x)=e^{rx}$. Plugging this in we find $$r^2 +\lambda =0$$

which is often referred to as a *characteristic equation*. Notice that the values of $r$ are real or complex depending on whether $\lambda$ is positive or negative. Technically you should also consider the case $\lambda =0$ separately.

Now your equation in $T$ is not second order and it is not constant coefficient. It is what we would call a *separable equation* (which is also potentially confusing in this context as this is not the same type of separation). Here it is the dependent and independent variables that can be separated, by rewriting the equation as

$$\frac{T'}{T}= \frac{-\omega^2}{t}$$

and integrating with respect to $t$, we find

$$\ln\vert T(t)\vert = -\omega^2\ln\vert t\vert + C$$
which has the solution
$$T(t) = T_0t^{-\omega^2}$$

Comment: THANKS! 2 questions: (1) with regard to the ansatz, would I be right to google Bessel's problem to learn more about how to get the characteristic equation? and (2) can you do the separable equation (the integration of T´/T) more step-by-step?

Comment: I recommend you read up on "constant coefficient second order differential equation", "Sturm-Liouville equations", and "separable differential equations". I don't think this post is the right place to cover several sections of a differential equations book.

Answer (score 2):

(1) First, you *assume* there is a non-trivial solution of the form $\;u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)\;$ , with $\;X, (or\;T)\;$ a function of only that variable $\;x\; (resp.\; t)\;$ , then

(2) Use the above with the given heat equation:

$$tu_t=u_{xx}\implies tXT'=X''T\stackrel{\div\text{ by}\; XT}\implies t\frac{T'}T=\frac{X''}X=-\lambda\in\Bbb R\;(\text{a constant})$$

The rightmost expression equals a constant since each side depends only on a different variable.

You thus get two one-variable dif. equations:

$$\begin{cases}(I)\;\;\;X''+\lambda X=0]\\{}\\
(II)\;\;tT'+\lambda T=0\end{cases}$$

(3) Remember: $\;\lambda\in\Bbb R\;$ can take, as far as we know, any real value. From what we know from one variabla Dif. Eq's., we begin with (I) and evaluate its characteristic equation:

$$r^2+\lambda=0\implies r=\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}$$

and we notice at once that we must check at leat the cases when $\;\lambda <0\,,\,\lambda>0\,,\,\lambda=0\;$

After some examples are made we can usually rule out one or two cases in order to save time, otherwise all the cases must be worked out.

And etc.

The poces is called Sturm-Liouville (SL) differential equations or cases of differential equations, and it is a very nbice and interesting part of PDE with eigenvalues, eigenfunctions, expression of functions as sume of egienfunctions and etc. (Too long to expose it here).

Comment: thanks! I know how to solve the PDE but my question is about the characteristic equation. I know when w^2 is positive that I will get the characteristic equation Acoswx + Bsinwx - but why??

Comment: @Zeeko Taht also was addressed in my answer: it comes fro the general theory of liner homogeneous differential equations, of which you have two (I), (II) . There we use the characteristic equation of the DE and depending of what its roots are (two reall one: different one of the same, or a conjugated complex non-real couple) The solution will like this or like that (the exponential, trigonometrics and etc.)

Comment: The problem is not to use the boundary conditions to evaluate the characteristic equations, the problem is HOW to get the characteristic equations.

Comment: @Zeeko The characteristic eq. of a linear homogeneous ODE of second degree with constant coefficients $\;y''+ay'+b=0\;$  is simply $\;r^2+ar+b=0\;$ , a quadratic equation.

Comment: How do you go from that to Ae^(omega x) + Be^(-omega x) for example